# Question of Normal Distribution ??

Tags: statistics

I do some exercise, and there is an interesting question, can anyone can help me solve it.
suppose that the heights in inches of the women in a certain population for a normal distribution with mean 65 and standard deviation 1, and that the height of the men follow a normal distribution with mean 68 and standard deviation 2. suppose that one woman is selected at random and independently, one man is selected at random. let W= height of the selected woman, let M= height of the selected man. Determine the probability that the woman will be taller than the man.

Comment: Can you find the distribution of the difference of the height of a man with the height of a woman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $W \sim {\rm Normal}(\mu_w, \sigma_w^2)$ and $M \sim {\rm Normal}(\mu_m, \sigma_m^2)$ are independent, then $$W - M \sim {\rm Normal}(\mu_w - \mu_m, \sigma_w^2 + \sigma_m^2).$$  That is, the distribution of the difference in height is normal with mean equal to the difference of means, and the variance equal to the **sum** of the variances.